# Non javascript multiline control with click event

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a requirement to have a link which spans multiple lines and has a click event server side. The problem is it has to function without javascript.

I tried using a button and styling it to look like a link. This worked fine as I was using the property

```
white-space:normal
```

which made the text span multiple lines.

However when I checked it in IE6 the text wouldn't wrap.

Does anyone know how to acheive a multi text line control with server side onclick event?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with server side onclick ? what do you want to happen when you click it ?

Comment: I mean using the server side code behind onclick event

Comment: @coder, why doesn't a normal link work ? are you trying to submit a form ?

Comment: What do you need to trigger the server side handler? A POST? Can you use a GET?

Comment: A normal link doesn't work because it requires javascript?

Comment: @Jared: It makes sense, you can't use `$_GET` for everything. @COder: I feel like you're just better off asking how to make text break in a `<button>` for IE6...

Comment: @Wesley Murch - It would depend on what the onclick was accomplishing. :)

Comment: I think you should have another look at what you're trying to accomplish here. As a general rule of thumb, something that looks like a link should behave like a link (and something that looks like a button should behave like one, too). Links trigger GET requests, and GET requests should be 'safe' - that is, you shouldn't alter data based on them. By making something that appears like a link 'unsafe', you throw off the user's concept of what to expect. I think it sounds like you should use a button, and make it look like one, too. If you post a mockup or test, perhaps we can suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I worked out a solution. It relies on the fact that a `<label>` element will focus/trigger the form element (inputs, buttons) it's attached to. Turns out, this will trigger buttons to be clicked as well. This means we can use the label as a clickable 'proxy' element for the button itself. The button can then be hidden.

I packed the button inside the label, and made the button invisible, then, the label can be styled to look however you like - it's a true inline element just like a link is.

Here's a demo - grab the code if you like: http://www.spookandpuff.com/examples/buttonText.html

**The HTML:**

```
<label for="buttonTest" class="buttonProxy">I'm a clickable proxy <button type="submit" id="buttonTest" class="proxied"></button></label>
```

**The CSS**

```
button.proxied {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        opacity:0;
        position:absolute;
    }

    label.buttonProxy {
        text-decoration:underline;
        cursor:pointer;
        color:blue;
    }
```

Be aware that older IE's don't allow you to interact with properly 'hidden' form elements: if you `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` your button, it won't work. Setting width/height to 0 will work, as will setting the opacity to 0 with an IE specific rule.

Answer (score 0):

I think a button is an inline block, so it will try to avoid wrapping internally if it can. There are a couple of ways of forcing it to wrap, such as putting `<br>` tags inside the button, or even using `<table width="1">` (again, inside the button).

Comment: `<br />` tags mean you would have to know where the line breaks will occur - which is basically impossible. The table trick will just try to make the element as small as possible, but it will indeed force line breaks - just not the kind you want.

Comment: IE retains the 'inline-block-like' rendering for buttons, and generally ignores any 'display' declarations you give it. I don't think it will ever run a button inline with a block of text.

Comment: @Wesley @Beejamin Sorry, I didn't understand the problem as wrapping the button as part of an existing block of text. (In that case my hack would have been to have separate buttons for each word.)